# Function(s) are being improperly executed/repeated within a switch statement. Rest of code doesn't execute

Tags: c, function, loops, switch-statement

So far `main()` executes fine and the `while` loop executes fine. If I put a wrong PIN in, program execution immediately stops. If otherwise, the program proceeds to through the rest of its execution.

I decided to test one function, `transfer()` and that's where I have problems. The transfer function only executes to the printf statements correctly. Instead of the program waiting for my input of which account to do the transfer on, it jumps back to the beginning of `transfer()` and keeps repeating…

The switch statement in `transfer()` doesn't even execute! Why?

```
//This program will mimick an ATM machine
//It will do deposits, withdrawals, and authentication

//Function Declarations
//float withdrawal();
//float deposit();
float transfer ();
void decision ();

float checking = 15050.00;
float savings = 8200.83;

#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int PIN;
    printf ("Welcome to Wells Fargo 24HR Teller!\n");
    printf ("Enter Your 4-Digit PIN \n");
    scanf ("%d", &PIN);

    while (PIN == 2016) {
        decision ();            //this starts the ATM choices user can select
    }
    if (PIN != 2016) {
        printf ("AUTHENTICATION FAILED");
    }
    return 0;
}

void decision ()
{

    printf ("I want to:\n");
    printf ("A) Make a Transfer\n");
    //printf("B) Make a Deposit\n");
    //printf("C) Make a Withdrawal\n");
    //printf("D) Exit\n");

    char selection;
    scanf ("%c", &selection);

    switch (selection) {
    case 'A':
        transfer ();
        //case 'B':  deposit();
        //case 'C':  withdrawal();
        //case 'D': break;
    }
}

float transfer ()
{
    float transamt;
    float chekbal;
    float savbal;
    printf ("Transfer Amount? \n");
    scanf ("%f", &transamt);
    printf ("\n Transfer Amount of %f", transamt);


    printf ("\n Which Account? \n");
    printf (" A) Checking \n");
    printf (" B) Savings \n");

    /*Right after this point, execution goes back to beginning of decision()
    program execution doesn't go through switch statement */
    char confirm;
    scanf ("%c", &confirm);

    switch (confirm) {
    case 'A':
        chekbal = (transamt + checking);
        printf ("Checking Balance is Now %f", chekbal);
        break;

    case 'B':
        savbal = (transamt + savings);
        printf ("Savings Balance is Now %f", savbal);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Reducing your code will help you to identify the culprit of most issues. Be sure to tag your programming language when asking a question, and make sure to format your code properly before posting.

Comment: Print the character you read with scanf and you'll see why.

Comment: Well , there is a `return 0;` after the `if` statement in `main` , if `PIN` is correct function is called , if not then `printf` in `if` is executed and function `return` `0`.

Comment: My crystal ball says after reading the float with scanf, a new line is left in the input buffer and read by the character scanf.

Comment: You need to use `" %c"` with a space before the `%c` to skip white space (newlines, etc) after leaving the newline in the buffer while reading the PIN.  Etc.  You're missing the `break` statements after the actions in the `switch`, so lots of functions get executed where you expected it to execute just one.

Comment: This is why you should always define a default case in a switch statement.

Comment: Due note that in the C language, a 'float' literal must have a trailing `f`  otherwise the literal is seen as a 'double'.   The posted code has two instances of this oversight

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: each code block in the `decision()` `case` statements needs to be terminated with `break;`  otherwise the code will fall through to the next case.  Which is probably not what you want.

Comment: when writing a `switch()` statement, always include a `default:` case

Comment: when writing the function prototypes, for functions that have no parameters, the prototype should have a parameter of `void`, otherwise the compiler thinks the code is indicating that any number/type of parameters might be passed.  (no `void` needed on the function signatures.)

Comment: when using scanf, with the %c format specifier, it is best to write the format string as: `" %c"` so any white space will be consumed before inputting the actual character of interest

Comment: when outputting some string using `printf()`, terminate the string with `\n' so the text is immediately output rather than being queued in a buffer until (in this case) the program ends

Comment: the `transfer()` function is prototype'd and declared to return a `float`, but the code that calls `transfer()` ignores the returned value.  AND the returned value is `0` which is not a float (although implicit conversion will fix that problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf` with the `%c` conversion specifier does not consume whitespace, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> All conversion specifiers other than [, c, and n consume and discard all leading whitespace characters

Pressing enter after inputting a transfer amount inserts a newline into stdin, which `scanf("%c", &confirm)` then sees and stores in `confirm`, that is, `confirm` now contains a newline. To see this explicitly, try adding `case '\n':` to the `switch(confirm)` statement; you'll see that the switch statement is in fact being executed, it's just that the value of confirm didn't match any of your previous cases. It's good practice to always add a `default:` label to switch statements in order to catch any unexpected values.

The solution is very simple, you just need to add any whitespace character before `%c` in the format string, since (from the same source above),

> any single whitespace character in the format string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from the input

So, `scanf(" %c", &confirm);` will first get rid of any whitespace in stdin (the leftover newline in our case) before reading the character that will be assigned to `confirm`.

Comment: I though default was more of personal choice. But if it works I'll try it. Could you explain the purpose of break and default some more? I'm new to C.

Answer (score 1):

You buffer storage the \n, this is visible if you put 300A after "transfer Amount?" and they "works".

A fast and dirty solution: put a getchar() after scanf, this "get" the new line.

```
//This program will mimick an ATM machine
//It will do deposits, withdrawals, and authentication

//Function Declarations
//float withdrawal();
//float deposit();
float transfer ();
void decision ();

float checking = 15050.00;
float savings = 8200.83;

#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int PIN;
    printf ("Welcome to Wells Fargo 24HR Teller!\n");
    printf ("Enter Your 4-Digit PIN \n");
    scanf ("%d", &PIN);

    while (PIN == 2016) {
        decision ();            //this starts the ATM choices user can select
    }
    if (PIN != 2016) {
        printf ("AUTHENTICATION FAILED");
    }
    return 0;
}

void decision ()
{

    printf ("I want to:\n");
    printf ("A) Make a Transfer\n");
    //printf("B) Make a Deposit\n");
    //printf("C) Make a Withdrawal\n");
    //printf("D) Exit\n");

    char selection;
    scanf ("%c", &selection);

    switch (selection) {
    case 'A':
        transfer ();
        //case 'B':  deposit();
        //case 'C':  withdrawal();
        //case 'D': break;
    }
}

float transfer ()
{
    float transamt;
    float chekbal;
    float savbal;
    printf ("Transfer Amount? \n");
    scanf ("%f", &transamt);
    // THIS GETCHAR
    getchar();
    printf ("\n Transfer Amount of %f", transamt);


    printf ("\n Which Account? \n");
    printf (" A) Checking \n");
    printf (" B) Savings \n");

    /*Right after this point, execution goes back to beginning of decision()
    program execution doesn't go through switch statement */
    char confirm;
    scanf ("%c", &confirm);
    // THIS GETCHAR
    getchar();
    switch (confirm) {
    case 'A':
        chekbal = (transamt + checking);
        printf ("Checking Balance is Now %f", chekbal);
        break;

    case 'B':
        savbal = (transamt + savings);
        printf ("Savings Balance is Now %f", savbal);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a major problem with the posted code (and why it continually loops) is the following code block

```
while (PIN == 2016) 
{
    decision ();            //this starts the ATM choices user can select
}
```

which results in the code never exiting, even when the user enters a `D`

Suggest passing the user entered menu value back to the place that calls `decision()` so the code can use that value to exit, if necessary

Some minor problems are:

the calls to `scanf()` are not having the returned value checked to assure a successful operation

The `switch()` statements are missing a `default:` case to (for instance) handle any invalid inputs

when calling `scanf()` with a `%c` format specifier, place a space before the `%c` so any white space is consumed rather than being placed in the associated variable

the returned value from `transfer()` needs to be a float, suggest returning `0.0f`